# C# psql WinForms Replace Index With CheckBox

Tags: c#, winforms, psql

So my question is:
I have a table named "Status", where you check/uncheck a `CheckBox`, and I have a table "Transaction" which have relation to table "Status", but as you may already know, it just shows ID when you display it, is there a way you can replace it(ID) with a `CheckBox` and get the checked values from table "Status"?

Here is an image about what I mean:

[image: Image, about what I mean]
I don't really have any code ideas, I tried to search, but nothing for my specific solution, the only thing I found was how to add a plane `CheckBox`, but that is it.

```
DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn stat = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();

dataGridView1.Columns[7].Visible = false;
this.dataGridView1.Columns.Insert(7, stat);
```

Comment: what's your data that you are binding look like...are you binding your data store on this lookup table?

Comment: @Ctznkane525 I use DataTable to fill datagridviews